# vscode show file changes with different colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I modify files on local machine, vscode will shows changes with different colors, blue means this line was changed and green means its a new line, like this picture:
[image: Image of vs code highlighting lines in the gutter with differnt colours]

but when I modify files with Remote-SSH, it would not works, so how can I check my settings to make this works?

Comment: do you have a SCM/git repo in the remote project, and is the file being tracked (committed once)

Comment: yes both files in local or remote are being tracked by git

Answer (score 0):

If the remote directory is symlinked sometimes does not work (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/309) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5970)). Changing the symlink with source directory resolves the problem and the gutters appear again.

A work-around is to install [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension and enable Gutter Changes view. It is a functional replacement for built-in gutter indicators.

Comment: thanks! yes the directory is symlinked, and its fixed when i change to the source directory

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)