VSCode doesn't show changes in the file editor
I'm using vscode on a ssh remote server and I'm facing a problem: The changes are not showing in the file editor even if they appear in the source control:
This is what shown in the file editor
This is what shown when clicking on the changes in source control
This is only happens in one of the remote servers (let's say server A), when I'm using another remote server (server B), it works normally:
This is what expected
I have tried to remove the ~/.vscode-server folders in the remote servers (A and B) but server A is still not working, and server B is still working fine.

Maybe somewhere there is settings.json file on server A, that overrides the visual settings, e.g. sets "editor.lineDecorationsWidth": 0

I tried to set "editor.lineDecorationsWidth": 10 and the line decorator width increased but still there is nothing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

unclear question. self answered with more detail showing that it shares the same root cause as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73441935/11107541, and is potentially a duplicate

I found the reason. This is related to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146611
The reason is that the home directory on server A is a symlink to a mounted device. I therefore open the realpath of the home directory on server A and it worked now.

Hi Tú Anh Nguyễn, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
